# Where should the objects created by a factory method be deleted?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

How and where should the objects created by `returnShapeType` be deleted?
This is a factory method demonstration program.

Please show the code.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape() {}
    virtual void print() {std::cout << "\nFrom shape print";}
};

class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle(){}
    virtual void print() {std::cout << "\nFrom triangle print";}
};

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(){}
    virtual void print() {std::cout << "\nFrom rect print";}
};

class CreateShapeObject
{
public:
    CreateShapeObject() {}

    Shape *returnShapeType( std::string arg )
    {
        if (arg == "Triangle")
            return new Triangle;
        else if (arg == "Rectangle")
            return new Rectangle;
    }
};

////////////

class EndDeveloper
{
public:
    CreateShapeObject obj;

    EndDeveloper()
    {
        Shape *p = obj.returnShapeType("Triangle");
        p->print();

        Shape *q = obj.returnShapeType("Rectangle");
        q->print();


    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? When? Where (in which class) the code for doing it should be?

Comment: The best strategy would be to render the question moot by not returning a thing that needs to be manually deleted. Smart pointers are a often used poor solution. But you could wrap the dynamic allocated object in a type of your own, that manages resources automatically.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you elaborate "poor solution"? I don't see a problem in returning a unique pointer, for example?

Comment: @andreee It is still a pointer, with pointer and referential semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza "But you could wrap the dynamic allocated object in a type of your own, that manages resources automatically. " Please explain this with example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to establish ownership principles in your design.

In your posted code, `CreateShapeObject` does not retain a pointer to the object that was constructed. It simply returns a pointer to the constructed object. This implies the calling function/class must take ownership of the object. They ought to be responsible for deleting it unless they pass the ownership to another function/class in which case the other function/class ought to be responsible for deleting it.

If you want to make `CreateShapeObject` responsible for deleting the objects it constructs, you'll have to update it to keep track of the objects it constructs. At that point, you may want to change the name of the class to reflect the dual responsibility. Something along the lines of `ShapeObjectManager` will make more sense.

Answer (score 7):

Using raw pointers is error prone. Use a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shape> returnShapeType(const std::string& arg)
{
    if (arg == "Triangle")
        return std::make_unique<Triangle>();
    else if (arg == "Rectangle")
        return std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid shape");
}
```

You can use it conveniently with `auto`:

```
auto shape = obj.returnShapeType("Triangle");
```

`unique_ptr` can be also implicitly converted to `shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape = obj.returnShapeType("Triangle");
```

Comment: A unique pointer is also a vocabulary type. It has the distinct advantage of saying, right there in the function's signature: "there is no other handle to this pointer". Which is a strong and clear message regarding ownership, IMO. It really should be the default choice.

Comment: I'd suggest to take `arg` as a `std::string_view`.

Comment: @StoryTeller But it is still the wrong thing, if all you want is polymorphism. It is used because C++ doesn't have better out-of-the-box alternatives. polymorphism shouldn't be bound to a choice between unique and shared ownership. That should be an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I really have no idea what you are on about, sorry. It's "wrong" when you want "just polymorphism", but there is no "just polymorphism"? It can't be the wrong choice for an option which doesn't exist. Someone has to manage the object's lifetime. This is the best default choice.

Comment: @StoryTeller A better option would be to hide the memory management in a polymorphic type with value semantics. That decouples polymorphism from the unrelated choice of unique vs. shared ownership.

Comment: @juanchopanza - You mean a sort of type-erasing "model/concept" holder? (Sorry, I don't know how it's called). I believe Sean Parent discusses those at length in one of his lectures. That *is* an incredibly powerful solution. And it avoids the base class of all evil scenario. I don't know if this is in scope for this question, though.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, something like that. But even a less smart solution where the `Shape` class holds a smart pointer to some `IShapeImpl`, and a factory instantiates the right `IShapeImpl` and passes it to the `Shape` constructor could work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Treat any use of `new` via the factory like you would treat any other use of `new`.
I.e. the code/class which uses `new` (via factory or not) is responsible for doing the `delete`, too.

Comment: that function doesn't return any variable which i can get hold of and delete in destructor. How do i delete "return new Triangle"?

Comment: By "that function" you mean `Shape *returnShapeType( std::string arg )`? I am confused. What do you mean by "doesn't return any variable"? It is not supposed to return a variable, it returns a pointer to a newly created object. That pointer is all you need to delete the created object.

Comment: does this mean that I should write like: `delete p` where p is the Shape pointer in the End user class's constructor?

Comment: Only if you do not intend to use the object after the constructor. Which seems a little odd. If you meant "destructor", then yes, that would be an example of how to do, if the destruction of the parent object is the time when you know that you are not going to use the object anymore.